# Set default value of ComboBox in grouping DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, grouping

I have this,

[image: XMAL]

Now, I need to set the default value of my ComboBox, (i.e., to the first value of my database table). I have tried to do this manually, `ComboScanner.Text = ""`, however, I get an error saying:

> Could not find 'ComboScanner'.

I am wondering if this is because I am using a DataTemplate, if not, how can I solve this?

Comment: StackOverflow has syntax highlighting, you should just copy your code as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting your ComboBox's `SelectedIndex = 0`?

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboScanner" SelectedIndex="0" ... />
```

Comment: when I try to to ComboScanner.SelectedIndex = 0 couldnt find ComboboxScanner.Thank u

Comment: @CPM: Why are you using ComboScanner.SelectedIndex? Just use `<ComboBox SelectedIndex=0` in your XAML